# Redis MAXMEMORY management volatile-lru vs allkeys-lru

Tags: database, redis

I am using redis as a datastore rather than cache, but there is a maxmemory limit set, In my understanding the maxmemory specifies the RAM that redis can use, should it not swap the data back to disk once the memory limit is reached.
I have a mixture of keys while some have their expiry set and others don't
I have tried both volatile-lru and allkeys-lru, as specified in the documentation both remove the old keys based on the property. 
What configuration should I use to avoid data loss? Should I set an expiry on all keys and use volatile-lru? What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swapping out memory to disk (virtual memory) was deprecated/deleted in Redis 2.4/2.6. Most likely, you are not using such an old version.

You control what Redis does when memory is exhausted with `maxmemory` and `maxmemory-policy`. Both are settings in `redis.conf`. [Take a look](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/redis.conf#L786). **Swapping memory out to disk is not an option** in recent Redis versions.

> If Redis can't remove keys according to the policy, or if the policy is
>   set to 'noeviction', Redis will start to reply with errors to commands
>   that would use more memory, like SET, LPUSH, and so on, and will continue
>   to reply to read-only commands like GET.

If `maxmemory` is reached, you lose data only if the eviction policy set in `maxmemory-policy` indicates Redis to evict some keys and how to select these keys (volatile or all, lfu/lru/ttl/random). Otherwise, Redis start rejecting write commands to preserve the data already in memory. Read commands continue to be served.

You can run Redis without a `maxmemory` setting (default), so it will continue using up memory until the OS memory is exhausted.

If your operating system has virtual memory enabled, and the `maxmemory` setting allows Redis to go over the physical memory available, then your OS (not Redis) starts to swap out memory to disk. You can expect a performance drop then.

Answer (score 3):

> In general as a rule of thumb:
>
> 1. Use the **allkeys-lru** policy when you expect a power-law distribution in
>    the popularity of your requests, that is, you expect that a subset of
>    elements will be accessed far more often than the rest. **This is a good
>    pick if you are unsure**.
> 2. Use the allkeys-random if you have a cyclic
>    access where all the keys are scanned continuously, or when you expect
>    the distribution to be uniform (all elements likely accessed with the
>    same probability).
> 3. Use the volatile-ttl if you want to be able to
>    provide hints to Redis about what are good candidate for expiration by
>    using different TTL values when you create your cache objects.
> 4. The **volatile-lru** and volatile-random policies are mainly useful when you want to **use a single instance for both caching and to have a set of persistent keys**. However it is usually a better idea to run two Redis instances to solve such a problem.

As given in the documentation

[Using Redis as an LRU cache](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache#eviction-policies)

Comment: I understand this, but I am not trying to use it as a cache rather I am using it as a database to store persistent data, my understanding is that once redis reaches maxmemory it will swap out data to disk. does maxmemory refer to total database memory or just the memory that it can take up in RAM. I am losing data when it reaches maxmemory

Comment: maxmemory refers to RAM allocated to redis

Answer (score 0):

Do not set that param if you're use redis as a datastore, it is used for cache scenario.